# How to read a next frame using JavaCameraView after few seconds in android?

Tags: android, c++, opencv

I am creating an app which involves input from the camera (live video). I need to process each frame (live frame) and I need to display output in the same window. I am using JavaCameraView in Android. Here is part of the code.

```
 public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame){

framesRGBA = inputFrame.rgba();

Imgproc.cvtColor(framesRGBA, frameRGB, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2RGB);


String ch = HelloJNICPP.checkequal(assetManager,framesRGB.getNativeObjAddr(),resizeFrame.getNativeObjAddr());
        return resizeFrame;
    }

}
```

checkequal is JNI function which will do some processing.Actually, this function is taking 2 to 3 mins for a single frame. I need to process next frame once the previous frame is completed. I agree that I need to optimize the checkequal function. For time being I need to read next frame after 2 to 3 mins and to display it in the same javaCameraView. How to implement this? Is it Possible or Is there any other way ?